# create a pricing matrix - sql or array of constants?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, matrix

I am planning to create a pricing matrix for a project in Rails. It's supposed to be a table of destinations and departure locations, and prices depending on where you came and are planning to go.

I am kinda undecided on how to better do this: either making a table in the db for this matrix, or making a mega array of constants. Problem is, the client should be able to edit this matrix so its most likely going the database route.

Anyhow, what's a good schema for this? Destination id, Departure id, then price? destination and departure ids will be foreign keys for a table containing all possible locations. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a db table.

The only thing constant about prices is that they change.

Added:

Pricing (also called product factoring) is something that I have a lot of experience with.

Your clients may also ask/or appreciate added pricing tools to help them get things right. Eg, your sw:

- could have reports that show the the prices in a manner that is designed for the people doing the pricing.
- report on the highest, lowest prices (to help catch data entry errors)
- Check out visual design of quantitative information for ideas on how to visually show the prices for the destination pairs
- make sure that a destination/departure pair is only added exactly once. (No duplicates in the other direction.)
- etc

You may also need to worry about effective dates for the pricing. Ie how to roll-out a new set of prices in a co-ordinated way.

Comment: so is my schema correct? just the ids of both locations then the correspongind price?

Comment: Check that there aren't (and won't be in the short term) additional parameters for the prices. Eg baby/child/adult pricing, seasonal pricing, etc. I use a table for "sku's" (Stock keeping units.) Each row contains many fields in addition to the simple aspects of departure/destination. Eg effective_dates, active (available for purchase at this time), etc. When changing prices, add a new row, don't change the price on the existing row (mark it as inactive).

Answer (score 1):

I would use two tables, Location and TravelPrice.

```
Location
----------
LocationID --PK
Name

TravelPrice
-------------
TravelPriceID --PK
DepartureLocationID --FK to Location
DestinationLocationID --FK to Location
Price
StartDate --date the price is effective from
EndDate --date the price is effective to (or NULL)
```

This allows you to keep a price history, important for reporting, billing, etc. Ideally you would have trigger on the `TravelPrice` table ensuring that there are no gaps or overlaps in dates for a given `DepartureLocationID`/`DestinationLocationID` combination, and that there is only one record with a NULL `EndDate` for that pair.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to a 3-column table because it's not necessarily a matrix - you might not travel from all places to all other places.  You want to be able to edit it.  As soon as you are done with your hard-coded version, you'll be asked to edit it.

```
LeavingFrom, TravellingTo, Price
```

Also, as the list of destinations grows,  query performance and code maintenance will become a factor.